# How do I install Python Babel library in it's trunk version?

Tags: python, flask, pip, python-babel, flask-babel

After hours of finding out why there are missing some documented functions in my Babel installation, I [learned](http://babel.edgewall.org/ticket/271) there are two branches of Babel development:

> Babel has two separate development paths (0.9.x branch and trunk) in
>   parallel for about 4 years now despite very few developers working on
>   the project. We try to resolve that situation by releasing a stable
>   1.0 version but well, real live is not always friendly to open source contribution.

Babel's FAQ [confirms that](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/BabelFaq#WhatdoIneedtouseBabel). I want to use [Flask-Babel](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Babel/) in my project. It's dependency in `setup.py` says I need just `Babel`. It means my `pip` takes any version installed in my environment or searches PyPI for the newest version, where [is version 0.9.6](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Babel/0.9.6). Unlogically, Flask-Babel uses functions which are not present in 0.9.x branch. Maybe I am missing something, maybe I am just confused, but **how can I easily install the trunk version, where is the most of new features? And how can I enforce using such a version in my `setup.py`?** How it all works for the people who use Flask-Babel? (I know, the last question is rather Flask-specific and should go [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/), but all the other questions can answer anyone else.)

Thank you for any suggestions. The bold questions are the most important, the rest is rather Flask-Babel-specific "nice to have".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `pip` with the url to the branch that you need?

```
$ sudo pip install http://svn.edgewall.org/repos/babel/trunk
```

After that, `pip` should be happy with the dependency:

```
$ sudo pip install Flask-Babel
...
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Babel in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask-Babel)
...
```

Regarding how to force a dependency in you `setup.py`. Since you're already using `pip`, you can give a try to a [requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html).

Comment: Here http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Download#LatestDevelopmentSourceCode they say it's not possible just to checkout their repository, there is some more stuff necessary to install the library. I tried to find the latest trunk package here http://ftp.edgewall.com/pub/babel/ so I could put it into `dependency_links` in my setup.py, but there is no version 1.0dev, the latest egg is just 0.9.6. I don't get it. How can
Flask-Babel (and Babel's official documentation) offer Babel functions which are not available in any
normally retrievable version of Babel?

Comment: @HonzaJavorek Note that running code from a svn checkout isn't the same as running `pip install` using the branch url (this does the svn checkout and executes `setup.py install`). In fact, in the same page, they recommend to install this way: `easy_install http://svn.edgewall.org/repos/babel/trunk/`. Hence, using `pip install` instead of `easy_install` should work as well.

Comment: But if someone does just `pip install myapp`, how can I assure it installs properly? I'll have `1.0dev` version of Babel required in my `setup.py`, but there will be no clue for `pip` how to get it. Does `pip` itself check also `requirements.txt` for svn/git/... repositories if it can't find the package in PyPI during the installation?

Comment: @HonzaJavorek According to [pip documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#subversion) you could use something like this `-e svn+http://svn.edgewall.org/repos/babel/trunk#egg=Babel` in your `requirements.txt`